# VI editor in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, editor

In the [features page](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/features.html) of Xcode 5 says it supports VI and emacs editor along with textedit and xed. But I can't find any documentation that describes how to switch editors. Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 1):

Those are not features of Xcode 5. "vi" and "emacs" are listed as editors available under OS X.

If you want "vi" support in Xcode you should have a look at https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim